# SQL to select common as well as remaining data using JOIN in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have three tables: wi_district, wi_group, and wi_training. I need to count groups and trainings based on districts. For this purpose I have used following SQL;

- SQL1

```
SELECT wi_district.dst_name, COUNT(grp_id) AS group_count, MAX(grp_created_date) as grp_created_date 
FROM wi_group 
INNER JOIN wi_district ON wi_district.dst_id=wi_group.grp_dst_id AND wi_group.grp_deleted=0 AND wi_group.grp_type IN (3)
GROUP BY wi_district.dst_name
```

The query counts group for each district. Likewise,

- SQL2

```
SELECT wi_district.dst_name, COUNT(trn_id) AS training_count, MAX(trn_created_date) as trn_created_date 
FROM wi_training 
INNER JOIN wi_district ON wi_district.dst_id=wi_training.dst_id AND wi_training.trn_deleted=0 AND wi_training.trn_beneficiary_type IN (-1,2,8,9,10)
GROUP BY wi_district.dst_name
```

The query counts training for each district. Now I need to combine all the results obtained from SQL1 and SQL2 and get the result in the form of

```
dst_name || group_count || grp_created_date || training_count || trn_created_date
```

The problem is whenever I used SQL1 LEFT JOIN SQL2 then it displayed the result respective to SQL1 where the result of SQL2 can't be obtained and vice-versa. Please help me sort out with this problem in MySQL

Comment: then don't use a left join. `left join` is "all matching records from the left table, any matching records from the right table". if you need all records from both tables, then you need an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can join the filtered tables and then group by the district name. Like so:

```
SELECT dist.dst_name AS dst_name,
COUNT(grp.grp_id) AS group_count, MAX(grp.grp_created_date) AS grp_created_date,
COUNT(trn.trn_id) AS training_count, MAX(trn.trn_created_date) AS trn_created_date 
FROM wi_district AS dist
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT dst_id, trn_id, trn_created_date
  FROM wi_training
  WHERE trn_deleted=0
    AND trn_beneficiary_type IN (-1,2,8,9,10)
) AS trn ON trn.dst_id=dist.dst_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT grp_dst_id, grp_id, grp_created_date
  FROM wi_group
  WHERE grp_deleted=0
    AND grp_type IN (3)
) AS grp ON grp.grp_dst_id = dist.dst_id
GROUP BY dist.dst_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use names like dst_name? It is better to write out the full name, so you will also understand what it means after a few months.

Anyway, this query should do the trick

```
select d.dst_name as district
,      count(distinct g.grp_id) as group_count
,      max(grp_created_date) as group_created_date 
,      count(distinct trn_id) as training_count
,      max(trn_created_date) as trn_created_date 
from   wi_district d
left join wi_group g on  d.dst_id = g.grp_dst_id
                     and g.grp_deleted = 0 
                     and g.grp_type in (3)
left join wi_training t on  d.dst_id = t.dst_id
                        and t.trn_deleted = 0
                        and t.trn_beneficiary_type IN (-1,2,8,9,10)
group by d.dst_name
```

Comment: You're welcome. Just make sure you have the DISTINCT keyword in the count(), otherwise the group counts are multiplied with the trainings per district.

Answer (score 0):

You need to DRIVE it from the grouping table. Like so.

```
SELECT  D.dst_name,  COUNT(grp_id) AS group_count, MAX(grp_created_date) as grp_created_date, COUNT(trn_id) AS training_count, MAX(trn_created_date) as trn_created_date 
FROM    wi_district D
LEFT JOIN wi_group G ON D.dst_id = G.grp_dst_id AND G.grp_deleted=0 AND G.grp_type IN (3)
LEFT JOIN wi_training T ON  D.dst_id = T.dst_id AND T.trn_deleted=0 AND T.trn_beneficiary_type IN (-1,2,8,9,10)
GROUP BY wi_district.dst_name
```

And if you only want rows if they exist on either table, add a clause:

```
WHERE NOT G.grp_dst_id IS NULL OR NOT D.dst_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Flag it as the answer if it was the answer :)